# How to work with IRandomAccessStream and DataReader?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

I trying make app that reads files. Files can be larger than 2GB so I can't fully load them into memory. Due to this I'm working on file reading system for WinRT which allow me:

1. Read file with partial buffer - load to memory pieces sized 5mb
   for example, then user checks if desired amount of bytes exists in
   buffer.
2. Give me multi-threaded access to file - for example I need to read file for 2 disconnected purposes.
3. Resulting system must use the least amount of cpu, memory and hdd time as possible.

Right now I designed something that reads file with buffer in 1 thread and I have some questions:

1. What happens between `DataReader->LoadAsync(N)` and `DataReader->ReadBytes(target_array)`? Does the first operation load data into memory and second put data to target?
2. `DataReader` (or `IRandomAccessStream`, I dont know exactly which one) stores loaded data in swap file (catch it with ssd drive: swap placed on hdd, second attempt to read same data shows speed like hdd). How avoid it?
3. Is my design of reading system (`file->buffer->user`) is suitable with `DataReader` and `IRandomAccessStream`?

Comment: @Yakk FYI, WinRT implies it's C++/CX, not C++/CLI

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Ah, yet another dialect?  Sorry for the misedit.

Comment: @Yakk no worries, and yeah, they made yet another dialect (which doesn't run on the CLI, has no GC so the `gcnew` keyword wouldn't be appropriate, etc), but it's *almost* the same syntax :-)

Answer (score 0):

Great questions, you're on the right track.

1. Yes, `DataReader->LoadAsync(uint count)` seems to copy the data from the source (disk, network, memory) and load it into the reader's intermediate buffer. Make sure you wait for the returned `DataReaderLoadOperation` to complete before you start reading from the `DataReader` otherwise you will encounter some hard to debug exceptions.
2. `DataReader` simply provides a wrapper around `IRandomAcessStream`/`IInputStream`'s `ReadAsync` method. Whether or not the file is swapped is decided by the implementation of `IRandomAcessStream`. Windows seems to cache files by default. [You can read more about Window's file caching mechanism here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218(v=vs.85).aspx) I looked at `StorageFile` and couldn't find a way to disable caching but there is a way to do it through the Win32 API's, [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx).
3. This design is fine; it works best as long as you plan to read the file sequentially, without seeking. When a stream attached to a `DataReader` is seeked, the `DataReader` continues to read at its current internal position. It is only updated once `LoadAsync` is called again. For your use in multiple threads, you can call [`IRandomAccessStream.GetInputStreamAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream.getinputstreamat.aspx) to create a copy of the input stream at the specified position and bind the `DataReader` to that.

Good luck using this terribly documented API.